# Validación Laravel de formulario con ajax sigue requiriendo un campo que ya esta lleno

Tags: laravel, ajax

Estoy enviando unos datos con Ajax para insertar en base de datos, la inserción funciona bien ya que la he testeado sin validar los campos y los inserta normal en la base da datos, pero ahora que quiero validar los campos que sean requeridos, aun después de llenar un campo y volver a enviar el Ajax me sigue pidiendo que llene un campo que ya tiene datos.

estos son los input:

```
<input type="date" id="date_init" name="date_init" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>

<input type="date" id="date_end" name="date_end" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>

<input type="time" id="init_time" name="init_time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>

<input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Este es el js con ajax:

```
$('#btnAgregar').click(function(){

  objEvent = recolectData("POST");
  SendInfo('', objEvent);
                
});

function recolectData(method){

  newAppointment={

    start:$('#date_init').val()+" "+$('#init_time').val(),
    end:$('#date_end').val()+" "+$('#end_time').val(),
    '_token':$("meta[name='csrf-token'").attr("content"),
    '_method':method
  }
                
  return (newAppointment);
}

function SendInfo(action, objEvent){

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"{{url('/agenda')}}"+action,
    data:objEvent,
    success:function(msg){
                            
      $('#create_calendar').modal('toggle');
      calendar.refetchEvents();

    },
    error: function (err) {
      if (err.status == 422) { // cuando el codigo de status es 422 significa error de validacion 
        console.log(err.responseJSON);
        $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(err.responseJSON.message);
                    
        
        console.warn(err.responseJSON.errors);
        // mostrando errores del campo conrrespondiente
        $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
          var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');
          el.removeClass("is-invalid");
          el.addClass("is-invalid");
          el.after($('<div class="invalid-feedback">'+error[0]+'</div>'));
        });
      }
    }
  })
}
```

y esta la función store el controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $campos=[
            'date_init'=>'required',
            'init_time'=>'required',
            'date_end'=>'required',
            'end_time'=>'required'
        ];

        $mensaje=["required"=>'El :attribute es requerido'];

        $datosEvento = request()->except(['_token', '_method']);

        $this->validate($request,$campos, $mensaje);

        CalendarDoctor::insert($datosEvento);
        print_r($datosEvento);

    }
```

y este es el json que devuelve el request aún asi haya llenado un campo

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
  errors: {date_init: ["El date init es requerido"], init_time: ["El init time es requerido"],…}
    date_end: ["El date end es requerido"]
    date_init: ["El date init es requerido"]
    end_time: ["El end time es requerido"]
    init_time: ["El init time es requerido"]
    message: "The given data was invalid."
```

Comment: Antes del `validate()` has un `dd(request->all())` y verifica que efectivamente la data esté llegando

Comment: @L.Flor Si llega la data ya hice el dd y efectivamente el request lleva la info

Comment: En ajax estás enviando un objeto con propiedades `start` y `end`, fíjate que no es lo mismo que estás validando con laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Ajusta la función `recolectData` para que los campos enviados vía Ajax coincidan con los campos esperados en la función `store` de Laravel:

```
function recolectData(method){

  newAppointment={
    date_init: $('#date_init').val(),
    init_time: $('#init_time').val(),
    date_end: $('#date_end').val(),
    emd_time: $('#end_time').val(),
    '_token':$("meta[name='csrf-token'").attr("content"),
    '_method':method
  }
            
  return (newAppointment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia lo siguiente, el primer parametro colocaste request pero coloca request->all();

```
$this->validate($request->all(),$campos, $mensaje);
```